# How does kernel allocates the space for the page table?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, mmu

I would say that at first the process gets allocated one page of the top-level page table.

```
  GPD      PD1     PD2      PD3   
+-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+
+  0  + +------+ +------+ +------+
+  0  + +------+ +------+ +------+
+  0  + +------+ +------+ +------+
+-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+
```

Total: 1 page for the GPD

Now, let's say the program allocates 2 pages (8KB)

```
  GPD      PD1     PD2      PD3 
+-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+
+  1  + +  22  + +------+ +------+
+  0  + +  62  + +------+ +------+
+  0  + +  0   + +------+ +------+
+-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+
```

Total: 2 pages, 1 page for the GPD and one page for the PD1

Now, if the previous program required another 2 pages:

```
  GPD      PD1     PD2      PD3 
+-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+
+  1  + +  22  + +  24  + +------+
+  2  + +  62  + +  0   + +------+
+  0  + +  16  + +  0   + +------+
+-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+
```

Total: 3 pages, 1 page for the GPD,one page for the PD1, one for PD2

Is it really how is done?